# TWIG select onChange make AJAX request with parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have PUT method in controller

```
  /**
   *@Route("/change-status/{user}/{status}", name="users_change_status")
   * ...
   **/
   public function changeUserStatus(User $user, string $status){
         .....
   }
```

in twig template there is a select that displays and changes user's status

```
{% for user in users %}
<select id="{{ user.id }}" onchange="changeUserStatus('{{ path('users_change_status', {'user': user.id, 'status': ???}) }}')">
     <option value="active" {% if user.status == 'active' %} selected {% endif %}>Active</option>
      <option value="pending" {% if user.status == 'pending' %} selected {% endif %}>Pending</option>
     <option value="inactive" {% if user.status == 'inactive' %} selected {% endif %}>Inactive</option>
</select>
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to send PUT request with user id and status when select option changes. This is javascript code

```
    function changeUserStatus($url) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: $url,
            async: true,
            data: { },
            success: function () {
                console.log('success');
            }
        });
    }
```

QUESTION:

How can I send selected option value as request url parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `onchange` attribute from the select field.

```
<select class="select-status" base-url="{{ path('admin_users_change_status', {'user': user.id, 'status': ''}) }}">
    <option value="active" {% if user.status == 'active' %} selected {% endif %}>Active</option>
    <option value="pending" {% if user.status == 'pending' %} selected {% endif %}>Pending</option>
    <option value="inactive" {% if user.status == 'inactive' %} selected {% endif %}>Inactive</option>
</select>
```

Setup a `change` event listener on the select field. Get the base url and append the select fields value.

In your `changeUserStatus` function, you can remove `data` (since there is no data being passed in) and `async` (since it is true by default).

```
$('.select-status').change(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('base-url') + $(this).val();

    changeUserStatus(url);
});

function changeUserStatus(url) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: url,
        success: function () {
            console.log('success');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that select form is inside for loop. I get error: Variable "user" does not exist. when I tried your solution

Comment: Ah that changes things

Comment: @blahblah Try that?